# NetBeans stops running after a while

Tags: netbeans

NetBeans is behaving laggy and also it suddenly closes after running for a while, can't figure what's the problem.

Comment: As first shot: start it out of the console and see if it throws any errors. Version of Netbeans and your JDK it runs with would also help. And maybe you might get better help in a Netbeans forum

Comment: Hey I tried it with console it worked fine but while I was writing anything in NetBeans it showed some exceptions in console.  @Jaleks